# Rearrange the file content

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file with content as

```
123 OneTwoThree
234 TwoThreeFour
345 ThreeFourFive
```

I want to convert this file into something like this

```
OneTwoThree  123
TwoThreeFour  234
ThreeFourFive  345
```

Here the first column entries must get replaced at 25th place.
If second column of original file have more letters that 25 then, rest letter must get skipped **that means it should remove all characters after the 25th** 
e.g. in above sample output file, `1` of first column is at 26th position.

Is it possible to do this with the help of awk, sed or any such command line tool ?

Comment: When you say if it has more than 25 characters, the rest must be skipped, do you mean remove all characters after the 25th ?

Comment: Yes..that's what I want

Comment: Look at my answer :)

Comment: -1 You say, “… e.g. in above sample output file …”, but your example doesn’t illustrate the point you’re trying to explain. Then, when somebody asks for clarification, you provide clarification *in a comment*. (You should [edit] your question to make it clear.) And then, given two answers, you accept the one that ***doesn’t*** answer your question, based on your clarification.

Comment: I was clueless for such answer...but the solution provided by Archemar was enough good to point me in right direction. Hence, I accepted the answer. Anyway, I'm editing the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to truncate after the 25th character of the second field you can use the substr fuction in awk.

File

```
cat file
123 OneTwoThree
234 TwoThreeFour
345 ThreeFourFive
456 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Output

```
awk '{printf("%-26s %s\n", substr($2,0,25),$1)}' file

OneTwoThree                123
TwoThreeFour               234
ThreeFourFive              345
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy  456
```

Answer (score 6):

what about:

```
 awk '{printf "%-25s %s\n",$2,$1}' file
```

See:

```
cat file
123 OneTwoThree
234 TwoThreeFour
345 ThreeFourFive
789 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
999 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABC
```

Output:

```
awk '{printf "%-25s %s\n",$2,$1}' file
OneTwoThree               123
TwoThreeFour              234
ThreeFourFive             345
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 789
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABC 999
```